# How can i do a sequential display of a list of image(awt.Image) with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a big problem and i need your help.

My application is with JSF and rich faces. I have a list of Image in my model (imageModel):

```
import java.awt.Image;
List<Image> liste_images = new ArrayList<Image>()
```

And i have to play them one by one (every 3 seconds one of them is display ) in the same place.

How can i do that with J Query ?
I must send the list of image to the java Script and then display them ?

Please some help!

Comment: seems like you need a normal image slider to me

Comment: Hello Spokey,
Help me please !

Comment: does your `liste_images` contain the image link?

Comment: No Spokey my list contain Image (java.awt.Image)and not the image Link

`image = ImageIO.read(new File(path_image));
liste_images.add(image);`

Comment: the easiest way would be to create a `HTML <img>` element, otherwise Javascript can't read it.

Comment: thanks I will try it !
And how can i send the list of image from the model to java script ?

Comment: you can not do it directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725734/how-send-image-from-java-applet-to-javascript

Comment: and if i have a method that convert image to byte Array ! 
`byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);`

It's possible to call this method every 3 second to change the actually image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you are using RichFaces:

## Image display

There is `<a4j:mediaOutput>` ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Resources-a4jmediaOutput)) for showing images:

```
<a4j:mediaOutput element="img" id="image"
    createContent="#{bean.paint}" value="#{bean.currentImage}" />
```

The paint method takes an OutputStream and an Object (provided by the value attribute):

```
public void paint(OutputStream out, Object data) {
    BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) data;

    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", out);
}
```

assuming you use BufferedImage.

## Image switching

There is `<a4j:poll>` ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jpoll)) which makes periodical ajax requests.

```
<a4j:poll render="image" interval="3000" enabled="#{bean.active}"
    actionListener="#{bean.showNextImage()}" />
```

the showNextImage method will get the next image from the list, I'm sure you know how to do that. :)

Comment: Thank you Makhiel, i love you hhh